# Routing via style violation Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, via, via-hole

I have a part i imported from manufactuerers part list and has the following layout:
[image]

This is the layout pattern in it's datasheet:
[image]

I had set DRC rules to have a min via hole size of 0.3mm and this is why this error pops up.
Should i simply ignore this error? Is there a way such that i still get all other DRC errors but this one doesn't show up?

Or would you remove the min via size rule altogether?

The manufacturers I am considering for this PCB have the following on their website:

[image]

Comment: Can this manufacturer actually do 0.2mm holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices include

- Change your minimum via diameter to 0.2 mm. Once you have 4 or 8 0.2-mm vias in your design, adding more won't change your cost much.
- Add these vias to a class, and make a special rule for that class with a 0.2 mm minimum diameter.
- Increase the via size to 0.3 mm, with some risk of solder wicking through them and starving the thermal pad connection of solder.
- Ignore the errors.